Custom Plugin IPA Server FreeIPA Post Callback Not Triggering
I have been having trouble getting this plugin registered and imported without errors in the error_log. I am placing it in the ipaserver/plugin directory and have given it matching permissions/ownership as the surrounding plugins. The issue I have now, is the dang thing is not wanting to trigger any debug logs. What am I missing?
import logging
from ipalib import api, Registry
from ipaserver.plugins.user import user_disable

register = Registry()

# Set up logging
logger = logging.getLogger('ipaserver.user_disable_hook')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler('/var/log/httpd/user_disable_hook.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

class user_disable_hook(user_disable):
    """
    Hook to execute code after a user is disabled.
    """

    def post_callback(self, ldap, dn, entry_attrs, *keys, **options):
        logger.debug("post_callback called")
        if 'nsaccountlock' in entry_attrs and entry_attrs['nsaccountlock'][0] == 'TRUE':
            logger.info(f"User {dn} has been disabled.")
            # End session code here
        return super(user_disable_hook, self).post_callback(ldap, dn, entry_attrs, *keys, **options)

def main():
    logger.debug("Plugin initialization started")
    try:
       api.bootstrap(in_server=True, context='server')
       api.finalize()
       api.Backend.ldap2.connect()
        api.Object.user.user_disable.register(user_disable_hook)
        logger.debug("Plugin registered successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Plugin registration failed: {e}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


You are not registering a post callback in your sample code. You don't need to create a new class derived from user_disable. Instead, create a function with the signature expected from a post callback and then register it to exising user_disable singleton.
from ipaserver.plugins.user import user_disable

def my_post_callback(self, ldap, dn, entry_attrs, *keys, **options):
    # some action
    return dn

user_disable.register_post_callback(my_post_callback)

There is no need to add anything else. See https://abbra.fedorapeople.org/guide.html#sec-5 for more details (this is the same documentation as in doc/guide/guide.org in FreeIPA sources, just rendered in HTML).
